# fl_lossy progressive in image's URL?

Tags: webp, lossy-compression

I've seen a few websites are having images with a quite strange path, like

`https://..../image/upload/fl_lossy.progressive,q_65,f_auto/c_fill,w_180,h_180/....webp`

Was this path generated by a specific/standart software? Does this URL path have a specific meaning?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some researches just figured out its Amazon Cloudfront feature, which lets you configure uploaded image on the fly by changing URL according your needs. Super easy to create preview (just a few kb) and full HD image from the same source.

`../fl_lossy.progressive,q_65,f_auto/c_fill,w_180,h_180/...`

so changing `w_180` and `h_180` in URL will change the initial size of image. Changing `q_65` will change the image quality. Probably there is some js (or other programming languages) classes provided. Will do further researches